# qt : Containing both opencv and opengl subwindows within one gui window

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl

Recently I want to write a gui application, and its appearance is shown below:
[image]

I used MFC before to write normal gui applications, but I have never used qt to write gui applications. But this time I want to use qt, so i'm wondering is there any way to implement such interface, integrating with opengl and opencv subwindows within one application.
Please give me some directions on:
1. Which kind of **widget** can I draw opengl and opencv subwindows in my application?
2. Is there any way to do event handling in those subwindows respectively?
3. How does qt support for opengl and opencv integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem.
In fact, I've used openCV and OpenGL in different projects, but I don't see any problem.

You have to convert opencv cv::Mat to QImage (see various posts on the problem on StackOverflow) and then draw on a QLabel or a subclass of it.
For openGL there are special classes: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-index.html#opengl-and-opengl-es-integration

You should use event handling as usual in Qt (signal-slot, you know).